# react native undefined is not a function symbol.iterator

Tags: react-native

I have error when I run my react native project.
It works some hours before and then I exit from app and run again and I got this error.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue so I added @babel/polyfill to my project:

> npm install --save-dev @babel/polyfill

and add to my App.js or index.js file:

> require("@babel/polyfill");